# Express not accepting post requests after 6 requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I'm working on a game, i'm trying to get the client to post/put data about the player to the server, but after 6 requests the server seems to crash, then after a minute or so it will accept another 6 requests and repeat. This is the post code:

```
app.post('/entityData', function(req, res) {
    //test = req.body;
    //console.log(test);
    console.log(req.body);
    //entityList[req.params.uid] = req.body;
});
```

I've got a fair amount of other code but these are all for get requests, which seem to work fine with the client. Here is the code my client is sending:

```
async function sendPlayerData() {
    let playerData = {
        num: player.getPos().x
    };
    console.log(playerData);
    try {
        let response = await fetch(serverIP + "/entityData", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(playerData)
        });
        if(!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Error sending player data to server. ");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

I get no errors on the client or server, so have absolutely no idea what i'm doing wrong. The only modules i've got on the server is a custom utility module and fs.

Comment: it looks like you are not sending a response from server to client.

Comment: wow i'm stupid was not aware that was necessary!

Comment: Why do you think that the server is crashing, what do you see in the server's logs? also as Badis mentioned, you're not sending a response back, try adding: `res.status(200)send()` after `console.log(req.body)`

Comment: I have a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73158637/post-requests-being-backlogged-after-6-in-express-unexpected-behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that i was not sending back a response, after i fixed that it worked.