# POST requests backlogged after six requests from same browser in express. Unexpected/Strange behaviour

Tags: node.js, express

I have an app which takes a long time to procces post requests.
if a client sends more than 6 requests in a short space of time (say 5 seconds), I get some unexpected behaivior.

for example:
serverside

```
app.options('/',cors({origin: "http://localhost:5050"}));
app.post('/',cors({origin: "http://localhost:5050"}),async(req,res) => {
  console.log(Date.now());
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
  console.log("----complete----")
  res.send("Success");
})
```

client side:

```
$.ajax ({
   url: "http://127.0.0.1:5050/",
   type: "POST",
   data: JSON.stringify({token:"62e2c285a01937cdb462985d"}),
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}).done(function(result,status,xhr){
    console.log("done");}
```

if the client makes more than 7 requests in the 5 second period you get the following output (server side)
output (in milliseconds since epoch):

```
1659038307446
1659038307703
1659038307985
1659038308260
1659038308528
1659038308818
----complete----
1659038312459
----complete----
1659038312712
----complete----
1659038312994
----complete----
1659038313266
----complete----
----complete----
----complete----
----complete----
----complete----
----complete----
```

as you can see the logged times the first 6 times are around 0.3 seconds apart (this is how fast I clicked the button on my browser to initiate requests), but the 6th and 7th logged times are spaced about 5 seconds apart. I would have expected all of the logged times to be spaced 0.3 seconds apart. Clearly node is waiting to finish the 1st request before starting to proccess the 7th.

Why is this happening, why the limit of 6, and is there anyway to override this behaviour?

edit:

I have found that after making over 6 requests on one browser then switching to another browser and making 6 more requests. Those requests from the other browser are immediately serviced. This does not happen on separate tabs. Only on a different browser. I deduce from this that express must implement some kind of rate limiting by checking the ip and port of the client or identifying the client by some other means.

Comment: I believe you should read up on the event loop https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: @HugoDos Thank you for the recommendation.  I found it useful but still can't answer my own question. I initially thought after reading it that express/node services 6 messages at once, so I tested this theory by trying to make more requests with a different browser (see edit). My theory was disproved, also six seemed quite a small number.

Comment: Browsers have a limit of how many concurrent requests they will send to the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

It is nothing to do with express, the behaviour is due to the inbuilt concurrent HTTP request limit of the browser.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62573165/what-happens-at-the-browser-level-when-a-max-concurrent-http-request-limit-is-hi

Like Phil said in his comment.
I can confirm this as I made 15 concurrent requests using another node runtime, and the logged times were all spaced evenly
output:

```
1659094583440
1659094583444
1659094583444
1659094583445
1659094583445
1659094583446
1659094583446
1659094583446
1659094583447
1659094583447
1659094583447
1659094583448
1659094583448
1659094583449
1659094583449
----complete----
----complete----
----complete----
----complete----
----complete----
----complete----
----complete----
----complete----
----complete----
----complete----
----complete----
----complete----
----complete----
----complete----
----complete----
```